# C#.Net Architecture for real-time updates for windows desktop client applications

Tags: c#, signalr, rabbitmq

Currently we have windows desktop software that is installed at customer premises and the software is polling a WCF service every 10 mins for updates on data.

I wanted to change this a real-time so when there is a update on server it pushes data back to the desktop client or web client.

The desktop client may be offline i.e. PC can be switch off or application is not started. In this scenario we would like to messages or updates to be queued

As we only support windows desktop client application so I will be using .Net technology.

This is the architecture that I thought of, please let me know if there is a better way to achieve.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions related to code and bugs in code. Please consider asking your question on http://serverfault.com/.

Answer (score 1):

[NServicebus](http://docs.particular.net/samples/step-by-step/) is another excellant tool for this type of thing.

Comment: I was considering of using Signalr (see link https://www.dropbox.com/s/yivd1hgpd1i7u3z/Real-time.png?dl=0). Please let me know if NServiceBus will fit better.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider streaming / queue platforms such as:

- Tibco RV
- Aleri
- RabbitMQ

Answer (score 0):

Consider Microsoft message queue: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For offline case you don't need any queue. The app will check for update when started. When online, you can keep open TCP or UDP connection to server and send update notification to client. It will be something like "Update notification service".